Compactness and Uniform Continuity
I'm working on the following problem
Problem Statement:
(a) Prove that a set $ K \subset \mathbb{R} $ is compact if and only if every continuous function on $ K $ is uniformly continuous.
(b) Determine if there exists an unbounded $ K \subset \mathbb{R} $ such that every continuous function on $ K $ is uniformly continuous.
My Attempt:
Part (a) — First Direction:
I proceeded by contradiction. Here is also a reference reference for first direction
Part (a) — Second Direction:
To prove that if every continuous function on $ K $ is uniformly continuous, then $ K $ must be compact, I tried the following:
Proof by Contradiction:

Assume $ K $ is not compact. Then $ K $ is either not bounded or not closed.


Case 1: $ K $ is unbounded:

Consider the continuous function $ f(x) = x $. While it is continuous on an unbounded set $ K $, it fails to be uniformly continuous because for any $ \epsilon > 0 $, we can find points $ x, y \in K $ such that $ |x - y| $ is large enough to make $ |f(x) - f(y)| \geq \epsilon $. here I am facing hard time writing it correctly.


Case 2: $ K $ is not closed:

If $K $is not closed, there exists a sequence $ \{x_n\} \subset K $ that converges to a point $ a \notin K $. A continuous function defined on $ K $ could approach a limit as $ x_n \to a $, but uniform continuity would fail due to behavior at $ a $.



Part (b):
I am considering $ K = \mathbb{Z} $. Since it is discrete, every continuous function defined on it should be uniformly continuous.
Question:

How to write a formal proof for part(a) direction 2.
Is my exemple in part (b) correct?

Any feedback or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance for your help!

In case 1, $|f(x)-f(y)|=|x-y|$, isn't? So, $|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon$ whenever $|x-y|<\varepsilon$.
Thus, $f$ is uniformly continuous.

Your example in (b) is correct.
